# Webkit Scrollbars not accepting RGBa values?

Tags: css, user-interface, webkit, scrollbars, rgba

I am styling some scrollbars on a webpage for webkit, and I want the track to be semi-transparent so that some of the background image bleeds through, but when I insert an RGBa value, it treats it just like an RGB value (without any alpha-channel). Does `::-webkit-scrollbars` not accept RGBa? I know it doesn't accept anything like `transitions`, so did WebKit skip out on other cool effects too?

Code:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: rgba(57,57,57, .6);
    border-radius: 8px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: rgba(156, 156, 156, .6);
}
```

(But - on my side - it is treating `rgba` as just a plain `rgb` value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout my [vertical jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NmvRb/4/) for doing it with a vertical page.  I setup a transparent track with a background image with the following:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: rgba(57,57,57, .6);;
}
```

For a horizontal page, checkout this [horizontal fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YbrX3/72/).  The difference with the horizontal code is I setup the page to be 100% height:

```
body, html, .scrolls {
    height: 100%;   
}
```

Then I wrapped the page content in a div, which is where the scrolling will happen, not on the page itself, like so:

```
.scrolls { 
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    background-image: url('http://www.evokia.com/images/large-background.jpg');
}
```

This is the workaround for the fact that it appears that the horizontal scroll on the page never gets the background of the page, so in order to get the transparent track we needed to create the scroll in the page.

Comment: This is something similar to what I want, but, it uses `box-shadow` to add color, and I want my scrollbar to be just a solid color.

Comment: More like what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes. In fact exactly what I'm looking for. And it works fine in the fiddle, but not on my webpage for some reason. :( Also, I feel it note worthy that I have horizontal (x-axis) scroll-orientation, not vertical (y-axis). Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Is this page online, so we can evaluate it with the rest of the code?

Comment: No, it's not. It's just a mockup right now. I have read that webkit scrollbars, though very customize able, still have some bugs (no transition effects, the bottom scrollbars act differently than the side scrollbars, and more). So basically, I guess, they're still in beta. [?] And like I said, I'm using horizontal scroll orientation, but I bet if it were vertical, like in your fiddle, it would probably work. :/

Comment: Oh, well. I will go ahead and accept this answer, cause, technically it did answer my question. Thanks! :-)

Comment: You are getting a white horizontal track right?  I see that too. http://jsfiddle.net/YbrX3/69/

Comment: Yes. Exactly. It also is slightly bigger than really defined for the bottom.

Comment: Yeah.. That does it. Why didn't work before though? It's basically the same thing.

Comment: I cleaned up the fiddle and added description of solution above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure webkit does support RGBa values, I've used `body::-webkit-scrollbar-track{}` which has worked fine.

I've also used the [Jscroll pane plugin](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/), which I've found to be very intuitive and this does support rgba values too. This can also support full webpage customised scroll bars and IE 7+ as well.

Is it possible to see your code to see if ther are any issues?

Comment: Oh, and me a jScrollPane have a rough history. I don't really enjoy working with that plugin. :P